# Scala split Array by comma and each item by quotes

Tags: arrays, scala

I need to split an array by comma in scala and each item by quotes.

scala offers mkString to split items, the following example uses it:

```
val args = Array("Hello", "world", "it's", "me")
val string = args.mkString(",")
```

And the result is:

```
Hello,world,it's,me
```

but I need each element enclosed by quotes as in the following example:

```
"Hello","world","it's","me"
```

I can implement it using a map like the following one

```
args.map(entry => s""""${entry}"""" ).mkString(",")
```

is there any builtin operation that does the same in a more polite way ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Or maybe use the version of `mkString` with option to provide **prefix** and **suffix** as below:

```
val args = Array("Hello", "world", "it's", "me")
args.mkString(""""""", """","""", """"""")
```

Comment: I think this one would be more readable: `args.mkString("\"", "\",\"", "\"")`

Comment: well, scala is well known to enforce readability and this is not precisely enforcing this xD

Comment: This only adds the quotes at the very beginning and ending of the string. I sounds like he needs the quotes around each item.

Comment: @wheaties That is handled by the second argument (`"""",""""`) of `mkString()`

Comment: @wheaties But I am getting `res0: String = "Hello","world","it's","me"` with scala version **2.11.7**

Comment: @AdityaSingh you're right. 4 quotes, I mistakenly saw only 3.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution looks fine. The shorter version could be `s"\"$s\""` but it currently doesn't work:
https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6476

Comment: The three-arg mkString is surely the better solution here.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I'd like to object. "enclosing each element in quotes" is surely an operation on each element, and thus a `map`. I find the `map`-based solution more clear, and consider `mkString` a little bit hacky.

Comment: Well, we'll have to differ.`mkString` is intended for exactly this sort of  thing.