# How to make a comma-separated string of all Row's values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

So basically this is what I am trying to do

```
insertUpdateRDD2.foreachPartition{ partitionOfRecords =>
  val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl)
  val s = connection.createStatement()
  for (row <- partitionOfRecords ){      
  s.execute(s"""INSERT INTO K_CPIREG VALUES ('${row:_*}')""")
  }
  connection.close()
  }
```

The Row RDD i have contains 88 columns and it doesn't make sense to write the values one by one such as ${row(0)} .., all the way to 88. IS there any dynamic solution for this ?

Comment: If row is some sequence then `mkString` method could help.

Comment: @Zernike `row ` is a `org.apache.spark.sql.Row`

Comment: What's the Spark version? Why do you use RDDs not DataFrames?

Comment: I am using RDDs so I can use foreachpartition. I couldn't find any way for efficiently inserting the dataframe into the SQL server table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Row.mkString](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Row@mkString(sep:String):String) method.

```
s.execute(s"""INSERT INTO K_CPIREG VALUES (${row.mkString(",")})""")
```

Comment: How can put the values inside a single quote 'val', otherwise it keeps triggering and error   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'val'

Comment: This is how 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38199709/scala-split-array-by-comma-and-each-item-by-quotes